# How to claim Virgin Train tickets towards Virgin Flying Club air miles, if not booked through their official website?

Tags: trains, loyalty-programs, virgin-atlantic

I frequently travel by Virgin East Coast trains (in the UK), and I know that you can use these train journeys towards Virgin Flying Club airmiles - if you book them through the Virgin website. I use a corporate booking service, so can't do this: can anyone advise how I can frequently (rather than just one-off) redeem my train journeys to Flying Club points?

Comment: Does the corporate booking service include your (Nectar?) card number when making your arrangements?

Comment: I believe it's a reward for booking with them, not for travelling with them, effectively funded from the booking commission. If I'm right, that'd mean there's no way to do it when booking elsewhere, as Virgin wouldn't have got the commission from the ticket